# Quick find can't search a record with odata lookup field

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, microsoft-dynamics

There is an OData lookup field called `first_name`. I can use the advanced find to search a record. However, I can't search a record through quick find.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABpVC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmxVy.png)

Comment: Its a general lookup field, why you say odata lookup? Did you configure the Quick view find columns on this lookup attribute ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.